# Can i use Team Explorer 2010 with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer

I think the title is very clear, but also i want to say why:
I already downloaded TFS 2010 and Team explorer 2010, but i'm still using VS2008 (with no short-time plans to change)
My question, can i use those toghether?
Also, my VS is just the professional version. I don't want to download the TE2008 because for my internet conection, it is just too big.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2010 client is backwards compatible with 2008 servers (though not 2005).  Details: http://blogs.msdn.com/teams_wit_tools/archive/2009/10/19/compatibility-matrix-for-2010-beta-2-team-foundation-server-to-team-explorer-2008-and-2005.aspx

However, it will not integrate inside the VS2008 shell.  If you want full source control integration you'll need to download TE2008 + SP1.

Comment: And the 2008 Patch http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=CF13EA45-D17B-4EDC-8E6C-6C5B208EC54D to enable forwards compatibility

Comment: If I read the question correctly, the question was if the client was compatible with the Studio.. not if it was compatible with a newer TFS server?

Comment: as @Bert says, my questions goes to know if VS2008 can use the Team explorer 2010, but I think (or maybe I'm doing something wrong) that it does not.
Thanks anyways!

Comment: See my answer.  You can use VS2008 with TE2010 side by side, but they will not integrate.