# tfs integration with delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, tfs, delphi-2010

We are currently upgrading from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2010. With Delphi 7 we use Source Connection to integrate Delphi 7 with TFS, but there does not look like there is going to be a Delphi 2010 version in time. Is there any other integration option out there?

Answer (score 2):

[VssConneXion](http://www.epocalipse.com/vcx.htm) is not ready for Delphi 2010 yet (there is a version for Delphi 2009 on their [downloads page](http://www.epocalipse.com/downloads.htm)).

Currently, I'm running the (Microsoft) Team Explorer for managing my source code check-out/check-in and work-items.
It works fine, even though it is not integrated in the Delphi IDE.

I've not tried which version of Team Explorer works with which versions of Team Foundation System ([this question has a bit more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698033/can-i-use-team-explorer-2010-with-visual-studio-2008)), but here are a few download links:

- [Team Explorer 2010](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Visual-Studio-Team-Explorer.shtml)
- [Team Explorer 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86)
- [Team Explorer 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=46473C2A-BB85-4461-BB27-4792A5DEF222&displaylang=en)

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

There's [athlant](http://www.devrace.com/en/athlant/), but it's seems there's no updated version for Delphi 2010 too.

I used [VssConneXion](http://www.epocalipse.com/vcx.htm) for years, but I gave up because they don't update it frequently, and you have to wait much months for new release, so I went to SVN with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), and since that day, I have never needed any IDE integration, it's work wonderfully without the IDE integration, but you may don't like it at first, but after few time, you will like it more than IDE integration.