# TFS and Builder 2009/XE4

Tags: delphi, tfs, c++builder, delphi-xe, c++builder-xe

I'm building a matrix to compare different source control repositories and which IDEs they integrate with. In essence, I need to make sure the source control integrates with all of the IDEs we use.

I'm trying to find out if `Team Foundation Server` integrates with `Builder 2009` and `Builder XE4`.

I found one forum with some old responses that say it wasn't supported in 2009... I'm curious if things have changed since then (Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/8c9c6502-20ee-4767-ba58-da78decb943b/)

Comment: I found the following link... http://www.epocalipse.com/vcx.htm which was linked from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677472/tfs-integration-with-delphi-2010 does anyone know if this works yet?

Comment: From http://www.epocalipse.com/buy.htm in the above links it looks like it works with 2009 through XE2 but not XE4... Anyone got anything that works for XE4?